# Display custom text on Add To Cart click/tap WooCommerce

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to display a custom text 'Your product will be delivered by Sunday if you checkout today' (preferably as a tool-tip) when my user is clicking on Add To Cart button on Woo. How do I go about it. Any sample code that I re-purpose for the same?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the following directory of woocommerce template `single-product\add-to-cart`. Then in each `php` file under this directory search for `add_to_cart_button`. You will find the relevant html tag to add custom tool tip.

---

Updated answer after conversation:

```
/**
* Custom Add To Cart Messages
* Add this to your theme functions.php file
**/

add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message_html', 'woocommrece_custom_add_to_cart_message' );

function woocommrece_custom_add_to_cart_message() {
global $woocommerce;

$twoDayFromNow = date('l' , strtotime('tomorrow + 1day'));
$messageContent = 'Your product will be delivered by ' . $twoDayFromNow . ' if you checkout today';

// Output success messages
if (get_option('woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add')=='yes') :
  $return_to = get_permalink(wc_get_page_id('shop'));// Give the url, you want to redirect
  $message = sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a> %s', $return_to, __('Continue Shopping &rarr;', 'woocommerce'), __($messageContent, 'woocommerce') );
else :
  $message = sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a> %s', get_permalink(wc_get_page_id('cart')), __('View Cart &rarr;', 'woocommerce'), __($messageContent, 'woocommerce') );
endif;

return $message;
}
/* Custom Add To Cart Messages */
```

Comment: Yes in add-to-cart directory you will find `variable.php` & `grouped.php` file. Please check the directory.

Comment: <button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_id() ); ?>" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt"><?php echo esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ); ?></button>

Found this line. What do I edit here? Sorry! Not a coder. Just trying to get some things done. I appreciate your patience with me :)

Comment: The snippet you took is from the file `simple.php` which is shown when user viewing simple product's page. `<button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_id() ); ?>" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt" title="Hello your product will be delivered ASAP."><?php echo esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ); ?></button>`. Have you seen added the attribute `title` in html tag `button`. Now if user hover over the `Add to cart` button title will be displayed as tool tip.

Comment: I want the custom text to display when they click the button instead of a hover. The objective is that they get to know the urgency of checkout if they complete the process immediately. So the text needs to be prominent but shouldn't distract the user to perform unnecessary actions to close the display, maybe a light box would help.

Comment: https://articles.uie.com/three_hund_million_button/ Please read this. Instead of blocking user purchase flow. Please add your content as side note in product page like this https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_alerts.asp

Comment: Yes! Something exactly like this but only when they click Add To Cart it should display right above the button. Should not be visible until they click the button.

Comment: I'll try this out. Once again thank you for being so patient with a non-coder.This will go to functions.php, right? Also, if I were to just display a text like A coupon will be revealed to you when you checkout. I will just delete $twoDayFromNow and replace $messageContent with my custom text, right?

Comment: Hey! It worked just like a charm. Is it possible to change the location of this message from https://imgur.com/a/pYllq to just above the ATC button https://imgur.com/a/0txA0

Is it also possible to edit date to something that enourages checkout immediately. Like 'A special discount coupon is activated and will be revealed to you during checkout' and have a timer of say 5mins with a coupon as an image? The coupon here is same for everyone.

Comment: Found this while browsing. Confused about where to add this code and make it display when Add to Cart is clicked

http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Create-Simple-Alert-Messages-with-jQuery-Bootstrap-alert-js.html

Comment: This `wc_add_to_cart_message_html` wordpress hook display like this only. If you need change the design please refer some expertise woocommerce theme designer. I know coding related things only not style or design.